# ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel - fields vs properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I refactored some common properties into a base class and immediately my model updates started failing. UpdateModel() and TryUpdateModel() did not seem to update inherited public properties.

I cannot find detailed info on MSDN nor Google as to the rules or semantics of these methods. The docs are terse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470933.aspx), simply stating:

> Updates the specified model instance using values from the controller's current value provider.

SOLVED: MVC.NET does indeed handle inherited properties just fine. This turned out to have nothing to do with inheritance. My base class was implemented with public fields, not properties. Switching them to formal properties (adding {get; set; }) was all I needed. This has bitten me before, I keep wanting to use simple, public fields. I would argue that fields and properties are syntactically identical, and could be argued to be semantically equivalent, for the user of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC will bind to properties of the inherited class.  The model binder calls something like typeof(yourtype).GetProperties() which returns all the inherited members just fine.

Just tested it out with:

```
public class PersonBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : PersonBase
{
    public string FavoriteFood { get; set; }
}
```

"My assumption is the methods are reflecting on the top class only,"

How would that work?  The "top" class IS the base class too.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that my problem was elsewhere. See my edit. Yes, reflecting with GetProperties() is exactly the issue, as opposed to GetFields(). I had expect to see the model binding update both public properties AND fields, since properties are syntactic sugar to masquerade as field notation. But, this is my lack of MVC.NET knowledge. Now that I know, its simple, but I'm not sure I like the differentiation.

Comment: >>The "top" class IS the base class too.
I meant bottom, sorry, typed that up fast... I should have said leaf class.

Answer (score 1):

this one made me curious too.
i made a edit form for a class `Manager` who derives from a `Person`
(after all, managers are persons too :-))

then in this action method

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Manager manager )
        {
            return View(manager);
        }
```

which wass called from a view with the `Manager` (derived type) as strong typed Model variable, when hovering the manager variable, it shows me the base class (it actually said: base: `Person` ) AND the one extra property for the manager

tried the formcollection too, and that also works:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection  formCollection )
        {
            Manager manager = new Manager();
            UpdateModel(manager );
            return View(manager);
        }
```

Comment: See my edit above, I finally realized, the base class had public fields, not properties. I want to treat public fields as properties, and semantically, they should be such, but the model binding ignores fields, it seems.